Activate XDP ZEROCOPY for TX without loading a BPF?
I was wondering, is it possible to benefit from the ZEROCOPY feature for data transmission without having to attach a bpf to the interface?
I was trying but seems like zerocopy does not activate if I don't attach a BPF to the interface. To make it work I had to attach a filter with XDP_PASS (which does actually nothing but i just needed any bpf to be attached just for the sake of activating zerocopy).
NOTE: I am using XDP for data transmission only (no RX).

What do you mean by "I am using XDP for data transmission only"? There is no XDP on TX.
